# Plugin question, How to insert a colon in a value box

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to be able to insert a colon into my number box. In this case, I would like to put a colon between 15 and 1 instead of the decimal, since it is describing a ratio, but when I do this it breaks the block. How would I edit or add to this code to make this possible? I understand that the code won't take a colon because a colon is not considered an integer value. Is there a way I can allow colons to be typed in the value box?[image] [image]

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying CTA rows
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Bridgwater plugin
 */

?>

<section class="block-number-row" data-duration="2000">
    <div class="numbers">
        <?php
        $numbers = get_field( 'numbers' );
        if( $numbers ) :
            foreach( $numbers as $number ) :
                if( $number['number'] ) :
                    ?>
                    <div class="number">
                        <div class="value" data-count="<?php echo $number['number']; ?>">
                            <?php
                                $decimal = explode (".", $number['number']);
                                $decimal_length = strlen($decimal[1]);
                                // $testvar = "Decimal Value: ".$decimal[1]." | Decimal Length: ".$decimal_length;
                                echo '<div style="display: none;">'.$testvar.'</div>';
                                //number has dollar sign, format with 2 decimals
                                if ($decimal_length == 2) {
                                    $number_formatted = number_format($number['number'], 2);
                                    echo '<div style="display: none;">2 decimal logic triggered</div>';
                                //if number has decimal, format with 1 decimal
                                } else if ($decimal_length == 1) {
                                    $number_formatted = number_format($number['number'], 1);
                                    echo '<div style="display: none;">1 decimal logic triggered</div>';
                                //otherwise, format number with 0 decimals
                                } else {
                                    $number_formatted = number_format($number['number']);
                                    echo '<div style="display: none;">else decimal logic triggered</div>';
                                }

                                if( $number['unit_placement'] == 'before' )
                                    echo $number['unit'] . $number_formatted;
                                else
                                    echo $number_formatted . $number['unit'];
                            ?></div>
                        <div class="label"><?php echo $number['label']; ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you want to keep the number input it might just be easier to replace the `.` with a `:` on output.

Comment: Were you referring to changing the decimal here? If so this broke the block and made it unusable 

$decimal = explode (".", $number['number']);

Comment: Did you create the fields? Just don't use a number field if you don't want to restrict it to numbers.

Comment: No, I was saying that you could replace the decimal with a colon using JS when outputting the final code.  It would literally be a 'find and swap' sort of function where you located the `.` and tell JS to change it to a `:`.